# When should I use CSS reset?

Tags: css, css-reset

I want create a new MVC project, but my question is **when should I use CSS reset?** Do I use CSS reset every time?

Comment: Define "Every time" - Do you mean every time you start a new project? Or on every stylesheet you write within a project? If you are authoring multiple style sheets then add the reset to the top of your global css file, or, if you are not having a global file, then link to the reset first at the top of your <head>

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS reset everytime. I prefer [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).